# Ruby insert object into existing sorted array of objects

Tags: ruby

I have the following existing array of `Dog` objects, which is ordered by the `age` attribute:

```
class Dog
  attr_accessor :age

  def initialize(age)
    @age = age
  end
end

dogs = [Dog.new(1), Dog.new(4), Dog.new(10)]
```

I want to now `insert` a new dog record and have it go in the proper place in the array.

Let's say I want to insert this object:

```
another_dog = Dog.new(8)
```

I want to insert it into the array and let it be the third item in the array.

This is a contrived example meant to demonstrate how I specifically want to insert an item into an existing ordered array.  I realize I could just create a brand new array and sort all the objects all over again, but that is not what I am aiming to do here.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Ruby 2.3+, there's an [`Array#bsearch_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index) you can use to determine the index you need to pass to [`Array#insert`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-insert):

```
dogs = [Dog.new(1), Dog.new(4), Dog.new(10)]

another_dog = Dog.new(8)
insert_at = dogs.bsearch_index { |dog| dog.age >= another_dog.age }
dogs.insert(insert_at, another_dog)
puts dogs.inspect
# => [Dog.new(1), Dog.new(4), Dog.new(8), Dog.new(10)]
```

This only works if the Array is already sorted (standard, when using binary search for anything), but it sounds like that's the case.

If you're using Ruby < 2.3, you don't have `bsearch_index`, but `insert` is still available, you can throw together a quick search for the index on your own and then use `insert`.

Comment: This doesn't work for both ends. You get nil for both the smallest and the largest new item needing insertion.

Comment: For the smallest item, I get index of `0` returned, though for the largest it does look like it returns `nil`, so if you get `nil`, just need to push it to the end of the array

Comment: ...which can be done by writing `insert_at = dogs.bsearch_index { |dog| dog.age >= another_dog.age } || dog.size`.

Answer (score 7):

One idiomatic way to do this is to just append and then sort in place. Arrays are mutable in Ruby:

```
dogs.push(Dog.new(7)).sort_by!(&:age)
```

Depending on your use case, you may want to consider an alternative data structure that offers better performance, such as a binary tree. You may also want to implement [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Comparable.html), in which case you can simplify to `Array#sort!`.

Comment: Thanks David! I guess I didn't turn off Java mode in my head.